# nginx config does not take action

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup a basic nginx server. Usually I'm not working with nginx and I ran in to some issues I'm unable to wrap my head around.

I have a debain server with all the necessary things installed (like php, mariadb, ufw,...) and I want to run my website somewhat like this:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx                 ->      /var/www/
http(s)://(www).lechner.io      ->      /var/www/domains/lechnerio/
```

I want both https and http and the domain with www and without pointing to the folder `/var/www/domains/lechnerio` and the IP Address pointing to `/var/www/`

First things first, only getting `:80` working.

I have the following config setup:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/doamins/lechnerio;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name lechner.io;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf;
        }
}
```

however, when I now try to visit the IP the nginx welcome site is shown. When I access it via domain, it also shows the files from `/var/www/` even though i reloaded everything. `nginx -t` is working. A link from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/lechnerio` to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

Any input very welcome!

Comment: did you `include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*` in `nginx.conf`. file ?

Comment: thanks for your reply. when I try to include it I'm unable to reload the nginx service.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration that Nginx is actually reading and ensure that the `server` block with the exact `server_name` is present.

Comment: can you check error message and add into the question ?

Comment: you must `include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*` in `nginx.conf` file. please add error message sine you incuded the line code above

Comment: the message + nginx.conf https://pastebin.com/Ccqk39j7

Comment: put `include` line into `http {`

Comment: ah ok, thank you very much. also changed it to include `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.*;` and renamed to lechner.config + relinked to /sites/enabled instead. however, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/doamins/lechnerio;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name lechner.io www.lechner.io;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name _; # everything else

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. just a quick question before I try it: are these configs in the same file or split in lechnerio and default?

Comment: Both works. In the future more you'll have website/app easier will be to maintain for one file for each